# While closing a window getting an exception

Tags: c#

I have a window opened on a button click. When i try to close that window (On clicking the cross mark), i'm getting an exception stating

> Unhandled exception has occured in your aplication.

If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.

> String cannot be of Zero length. Parameter name: old Value

Thanks in advance. 
Below is the code:

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.cmbColumnCombo.DataSource = cmbList;
f.ShowDialog();

for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(f.txtfind.Text.ToLower()))
    {
        //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString().ToLower().Replace(f.txtfind.Text.ToLower(), f.txtreplace.Text);
        //bulidDataRow(i);
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString().Replace(f.txtfind.Text, f.txtreplace.Text);
        bulidDataRow(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. You should be able to get this easily if you debug the application. Also, please format the code in your post to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that code is failing on `Replace(f.txtfind.Text, f.txtreplace.Text)`, because `f.txtfind.Text` is empty string.

[String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

> ArgumentException. oldValue is the empty string ("").

Validate it before passing to `Replace` method.

Example:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.txtfind.Text))
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString().Replace(f.txtfind.Text, f.txtreplace.Text);
}
```